# Using `exec()` in an autoloader

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc, spl

After reviewing autoloader functions on the site, I didn't see anything like this, and I was wonder what may be wrong with this?

```
function findNloader($classFile){
    $file = exec("find ./ -name ".$classFile.".php"); 
    if(file_exists($file)){
        return require $file; 
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

The shell command returns `false` if somebody were to ever manage to inject something like:

`../../../../sudoers`  or the like...

And of course, it could be used with
`spl_autoload_register()` -- and if the file path were configured properly, it could find anything without chaining down autoload functions.  I understand that if it were pointed at a very large project, it might be resource intensive -- but with a direct enough focus, is there anything else wrong with this?

It could then be shortened into:

```
public function findnload($class) {
    return (file_exists($st = exec("find ./ -name ".$class.".php")) ?
    require $st : false);
}
```

And that looks quite elegant, to me.
Or if you want to be safe:

```
public function findnload($class) {
    return (file_exists($st = exec("find ./ -name ".$class.".php")) &&
           (length($class) < $thirtyTwoOrSo) || ($someOtherSafetyCriteria)
           ?
    require $st : false);
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Is this your own code, and is it working?

Comment: Yes - ! And yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are good reasons why you don't find (many, if any) examples of autoloaders or other functions that are built around the 2 things you are relying on:

- `exec`: sometimes, functions like `passthru`, `exec` an the like are your only option. But not when it comes to auto-loading classes. You're not using the right tool for the job, and are in fact using what can only be described as a *dangerous function*. More on this later.
- `find`: 2 problems that might occur here: `find` is not available, what then? Your autoloader won't work. Another scenario is one where `find` *is* present, but the user running PHP, does not have the rights required to use it

So why is `exec` dangerous?

Imagine using a modern dependency, like doctrine. Somewhere in your code, the `ClassLoader` class is used. Your autoloader kicks in:

```
function findNloader($classFile)
{
    $file = exec("find ./ -name ".$classFile.".php"); 
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
    }
}
```

What is the value of `$classFile` going to be? Well, doctrine's `ClassLoader` class is namespaced, its full name, and with it the value of `$classFile` will be `Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader`. Pass that through to your function, and you'll get:

```
$file = exec("find ./ -name Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader.php");
```

Now I'm not going into details, but I'm assuming it's pretty obvious that those backslashes are a problem. And a big one at that. Because you're concatenating them into a new string, the backslashes aren't properly escaped.But the biggest problem, by a country mile, is the simple fact that, even if properly escaped, the `\` character assumes a different meaning depending on the OS.

*Other problems:*
Not only are you not checking the exit status of `find`, you're not capturing the full output of the command, and worst of all: You're not handling possible errors.
Rule one when writing vital components of any system, be it a web-app or a low-level piece of embedded software: *Embrace Murphy's laws: Whatever can go wrong, will go wrong*.

Add to that the mantra of webdevelopment: *Never trust the network*, and I think it safe to say that, in an attempt to write a short/small autoloader, you've undermined reliability, scalability and general security. Not a fair trade-off if you ask me.

***Things to consider:***

- Namespaces: As I've already explained above, your autoloader does not handle namespaces.
- Pseudo-namespaces: In the pre-namespace era, most sizable projects were pseudo-namespaced. Think Zend Framework 1.x and the like. Classes had names like `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, and these classes were located in the Zend root directory, under `Db/Table`. The underscores formed the path. Your autoloader doesn't take those (very common) cases into account.
- Don't reinvent the wheel, be lazy. Many autoloaders have been written before, and many will be written in the future. But generally, things like Symfony2's excellent, and easy to use [`UniversalClassLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php) will work fine for small, to mid-sized projects.

If you have a bigger project, read through [the composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading). Composer creates autoloaders, that use classmaps, and other simple, but clever tricks to ensure the right class is loaded at the right time, with minimal overhead.

One of the things that sets a programmer apart is being lazy, in a clever way. Not wasing time, effort and brain-power on something that has been written before is one of those examples of clever laziness.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem I see with this is that you are assuming a few things:

- **I am running Linux** - Are you? The production server might, but are you locally running linux as well? Maybe, but will the next collaborator/developer?
- **My Linux distro supports `find`** - That also may or may not be true. Some distros will have that built in, some will not.

You are tying yourself to a specific environment, that's not good. A better approach would be to make sure that the class file sits under the path you expect it to, relatively to a file you know where it is relatively to the project.

Comment: But these assumptions are just as fundamental as : 

I have php installed - & it is the latest version of php -- 

These seem like very reasonable assumptions.

Comment: @rm-vanda: No they aren't. You can't run a PHP script without PHP. You can run a PHP script on Windows, which will pretty much instantly break both above points.

Comment: //EDITED: 

That's my point exactly~ You can't run a shell command without Linux- the same way you can't run a PHP script without PHP-
Sure, it is something of a needless dependency, but it will always suit my needs. I will always be running on Linux, and I'm 90% sure that the three different distros I'll be workind with all support `find` 
Thus, this dependency will never be an inconvenience for me, personally, it seems that the gain of this script is better than the caveat "it wont run on a windoze server" -- do you agree, or is there a larger implication I should consider?

Comment: @rm-vanda: Not supporting windows is one thing (it's only 10% of the server market, last time I checked). What _is_ a problem is not supporting dependencies like doctrine, or Symfony components. Another thing: Sure, linux shell commands, but the need to be installed + PHP must have the rights to use them. It's not inconceivable for a server to disable `find`. Lastly, windows also supports shell commands, what makes you say that it doesn't? all systems have a command line in some form or antoher